# back pressed should bring the refreshed activity

Tags: android, android-intent, savestate

Hey guys 
Activity A fires intent on activity B and then on back pressed of activity B the saved state of Activity A is shown.

I want to show the updated / refreshed state of activity A when back pressed on Activity B

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then refresh your data in `onResume()` of activity A.

Comment: cant i use something like intent.setFlag??? when activity A fires intent on Activity B

Comment: thanks it worked i have just placed oncreate(null) in onresume and i got it working

Comment: @abhishek: Please do *not* do that. `onResume()` will be called after `onCreate()` when the activity starts up. Just move your load-the-data code from `onCreate()` to `onResume()` please. Never call a lifecycle method like `onCreate()` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You should override `onResume()` method in your Activity A and update state there.

Comment: cant i use something like intent.setFlag??? when activity A fires intent on Activity B

Answer (score 0):

If you're using multiple different activities you can also use startActivityForResult() and then perform post-result processing by overriding the onActivityResult method. This also gives you the option to perform different tasks based on the result and the activity that the user was just returned from.